# Regex for replacing markdown links with <a> ONLY if link does not contain http

Tags: python, regex, markdown

I'm working on a python application that tries to reuse markdown from github pages and I need to handle links a particular way.  I currently use the following to convert markdown links to what I need:

```
filterString = '([^\!]|^)\[(.+)\]\((.+)\)'
filteredPage = re.sub(filterString, r"""<a href='#' onclick='requestPage("\3");'>\2</a>""", pageContent)
```

This converts something like:

```
[Getting Started](gettingStarted.md)
```

to

```
<a href='#' onclick='requestPage("gettingStarted.md");'>Getting Started</a>
```

This currently ignores links for images (preceded by a '!') which is as desired.  The problem is that some of the markdown contains external links that I do not want converted.

I want to use the substitution on:

```
[Getting Started](gettingStarted.md)
```

but not either of these:

```
![Getting Started](gettingStarted.png)
[Getting Started](https://www.gettingstarted.com)
```

I've seen examples of matching things that don't begin with something, but since I'm trying to match within a certain position (i.e, match when in parenthesis after something in brackets that doesn't start with an !) I'm not sure how to accomplish the not match on 'http'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead right after matching the opening parenthesis `\((?!http)` to assert not http.

If you want to match between `[]` and `()` you could also use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to not over match the braces.

If you make the first group non capturing `(?:` you could do the replacement with group `\2` and group `\1`

```
(?:[^\!]|^)\[([^\[\]]+)\]\((?!http)([^()]+)\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fQGUKn/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/8oKIKd)

For example

```
import re

filterString = '(?:[^\!]|^)\[([^\[\]]+)\]\((?!http)([^()]+)\)'
strings = [
    "[Getting Started](gettingStarted.md)",
    "![Getting Started](gettingStarted.png)",
    "[Getting Started](https://www.gettingstarted.com)"
]

for pageContent in strings:
    filteredPage = re.sub(filterString, r"""<a href='#' onclick='requestPage("\2");'>\1</a>""", pageContent)
    print(filteredPage)
```

Output

```
<a href='#' onclick='requestPage("gettingStarted.md");'>Getting Started</a>
![Getting Started](gettingStarted.png)
[Getting Started](https://www.gettingstarted.com)
```